# Tridion Search is not working

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

During upgrade from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1 we have configured search service as instructed in the Installation manual.

When we try to search ".aspx" word in the entire content it is giving error.

```
(80040356) The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.Unable to get the list of search results.Error occured while processing the request: Not Found.
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.ProcessResponse(HttpWebRequest,Boolean,Boolean,String&)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Post(String,String,String&)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Query(String,Int32,Nullable`1,String&)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResultsFromSolr(SearchQueryData,Int32,Nullable`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResultsFromSolr(SearchQueryData,Int32,Nullable`1)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchQueryEngine.GetSearchResults(SearchQueryData,Int32,Int32)
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.ComWrapper.SearchQueryEngineFacade.GetSearchResults(Int32,Int32)
SearchBLST.GetListData
SearchBLST.GetSearchResults
SearchBLST.GetSearchResultsEx
Search.GetSearchResultsEx
```

How can we troubleshoot the issue?

```
 <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
    <section name="tridionConfigSections" type="Tridion.Configuration.ConfigurationSections, Tridion.Common, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
    <section name="tridion.common" type="Tridion.Configuration.CommonSettings, Tridion.Common, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
    <section name="solrHost" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchHost.Configuration.SolrHostConfiguration, TcmSearchHost, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b"/>
  </configSections>
  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
      <add name="TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" keyContainerName="TridionRsaKeyContainer" useMachineContainer="true" description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt" type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, 
           System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
  <tridionConfigSections>
    <sections>
      <clear/>
      <add/>
      <add name="loggingConfiguration"/>
    </sections>
  </tridionConfigSections>
  <tridion.common>
    <tracing enabled="false">
      <parameterValueTruncation default="50">
        <parameterTypes>
          <clear/>
          <!-- Do not remove or change the settings for type System.Data.IDataRecord -->
          <add type="System.Data.IDataRecord" assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" maxLength="0"/>
        </parameterTypes>
      </parameterValueTruncation>
    </tracing>
  </tridion.common>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="false" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Tridion Console Trace Listener" formatter="Trace Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Tridion.Logging.TridionConsoleTraceListener, Tridion.Logging, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b" initializeData=""/>
      <add name="Tridion Debug Trace Listener" formatter="Trace Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Tridion.Logging.TridionDebugTraceListener, Tridion.Logging, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b" initializeData=""/>
      <add name="Tridion Event Log" EventLog="Tridion" formatter="Event Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Tridion.Logging.TridionEventLogTraceListener, Tridion.Logging, Version=6.1.0.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b" initializeData=""/>
      <add name="Log File" formatter="Trace Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" fileName="D:\Tridion\log\TcmSearchHost.log"/>
      <add name="Trace File" formatter="Trace Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53" fileName="D:\Tridion\log\TcmSearchHost.trace.log"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add name="Log Text Formatter" template="{timestamp} &lt;{win32ThreadId}&gt; {message}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
      <add name="Trace Text Formatter" template="{timestamp(HH:mm:ss.ffff)} &lt;{win32ThreadId}&gt; {message}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
      <add name="Event Text Formatter" template="{message}

Component: {keyvalue(component)}
Errorcode: {keyvalue(errorcode)}
User: {keyvalue(username)}

{keyvalue(stacktrace)}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=349a39f202fa9b53"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Tridion.Logging.LoggingCategory.Tracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Trace File"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchHost.LogCategory">
        <listeners>
          <!--add name="Tridion Console Trace Listener"/-->
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General"/>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="Information" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Tridion Event Log"/>
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings"/>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <!--To configure this Solr Instance as Master enable this solrHost xml node and disbale the other solrHost xml node-->
  <!--<solrHost heartbeatTimeout="300" solrHome="%TRIDION_CM_HOME%\Libraries\solr-home" solrDataDir="%TRIDION_CM_HOME%\Search\solr-data" solrLogDir="%TRIDION_CM_HOME%\Log" jvmOptions="-Xmx768m -Xms768m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=conf/jaaslogin.conf -Djava.security.auth.policy=conf/jaas.policy -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf\log4j.properties -Djava.class.path=start.jar;lib\* -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Denable.master=true" jvmFilePath="">-->
  <!--To configure this Solr Instance as slave enable this solrHost xml node and disbale the other solrHost xml node. Set the -Dmaster.url, -Dmaster.authUser="MASTER_SOLR_INSTANCE_USER_NAME" and -Dmaster.authPassword-->
  <!--<solrHost heartbeatTimeout="300" solrHome="%TRIDION_CM_HOME%\Libraries\solr-home" solrDataDir="%TRIDION_CM_HOME%\Search\solr-data" solrLogDir="%TRIDION_CM_HOME%\Log" jvmOptions="-Xmx768m -Xms768m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=conf/jaaslogin.conf -Djava.security.auth.policy=conf/jaas.policy -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf\log4j.properties -Djava.class.path=start.jar;lib\* -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Denable.slave=true -Dmaster.url=MASTER_SOLR_INSTANCE_URL -Dmaster.authUser=MASTER_SOLR_INSTANCE_USER_NAME -Dmaster.authPassword=MASTER_SOLR_INSTANCE_PASSWORD" jvmFilePath="">-->
  <solrHost heartbeatTimeout="300" jvmOptions="-Xmx768m -Xms768m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=conf/jaaslogin.conf -Djava.security.auth.policy=conf/jaas.policy -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf\log4j.properties -Djava.class.path=start.jar;lib\* -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US" jvmFilePath="" solrHome="D:\Tridion\solr-home\" solrDataDir="D:\Tridion\solr-data\" solrLogDir="D:\Tridion\log\">
    <jetty port="8983" stopControlKey="#SdlTridionJettySolrKey#" stopControlPort="8079" mainClassName="org/mortbay/start/Main" jettyConfigurationArguments="conf\jetty-jmx.xml conf\jetty.xml conf\jetty-logging.xml" home="D:\Tridion\solr-jetty\" tempDir="C:\Windows\TEMP\" logDirectory="D:\Tridion\log\"/>
  </solrHost>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <!--Enable Server GC mode for better performance in CLR 4.0. Note that this may lead to memory issues in CLR 2.0.-->
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What happens if you search for other text?  Something like *text*.  Also, did you run the TcmReIndex.exe file to update your search collection?

Comment: This type of question should really be asked in ServerFault, not StackOverflow: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tridion

Answer (score 6):

To troubleshoot the Search, first things I would try is to search with different search terms and see if they all return the same result (an error in your case).

Next is to check if the `Tridion Content Manager Search Host` service and the `Tridion Content Manager Search Indexer` service are running. If they are, see if restarting them makes any change to the situation.

When my `Tridion Content Manager Search Host` service is stopped, I get a different error, indicating the connection can't be established. So my thoughts would go out to a configuration error (the 404 mentioned in there makes me wonder if SOLR did install correctly). Check the settings in your MMC snap-in, and also check (like @robrtc mentioned) if you can run the reindex as described in the [upgrade manual](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_362FC04056E04C28B60446031B93A078)

Comment: After ReIndexing, Restarting both the services and checking the MMC snap in settings, we are not getting the error anymore.  But we are also not getting search results.  Yes we searched with different search terms.

Comment: While executing upgrade steps given in Upgrade manual we came accross : maxFieldLength is set to 10000 in solrconfig.xml, but in TcmSearchHost.exe.config we did not find attribute called jvmArguments rather we have attribut jvmOptions. Attaching TcmSearchHost.exe.config in main question.

Comment: We did a ReIndexing, now we are able to see search results with various search terms.  Over the weekend we also faced memory issues on server.  TCMSearchHost.exe is consuming big amount of memory. maxFieldLength in solrconfig.xml is set to 10000 TcmSearchHost.exe.config is pasted in main question, any idea why memory is over shooting.